# Suppose $u_{xx}+u_{yy} = 1$ has a radial solution on the annulus $ a < r < b$ and that $u(x,y)$ is zero at both $r=a$ and $r=b.$ Solve the PDE.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Using the polar form of the Laplace equation and the fact that the solution is radial I get that,

$$\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial r^2} + \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial u}{\partial r} = 1.$$

From here, do we just solve this like a normal nonhomogenous ODE initial value problem? If so, would initial conditions be $u(a)=0$ and $u(b)=0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial r^2} + \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial u}{\partial r} = 1
$$
You can simply rewrite the DE as:
$$r\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial r^2} + \frac{\partial u}{\partial r} = r$$
$$(ru')'= r$$
$$u'=\dfrac {r}2+\dfrac {C_1}r$$
$$u(r)=\dfrac {r^2}4+ C_1\ln r+C_2$$